# How to search inside current xml file in eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I cannot figure out how to search for text inside an individual XML file from Eclipse. Basically if I am editing one of my xml layout files, and I hit CTL + H -> file search -> Selected resources radio button checked, I always get '0 results in empty scope' as my results. Google hasn`t given me any help on this.

My workaround is to choose 'Workspace' instead of 'Selected resources' and then navigate to the file I want in my search results which is time-consuming. Why doesn't eclipse recognize my current XML file as a selected resource like it does with java files? Has anyone else had this issue? I`m using Eclipse ADT 23.0.2.129578

Comment: Are you sure the *File name patterns* option in the Search dialog is set to include `.xml` files when you do this? I just tried with the standard XML editor (don't have ADT installed) and it behaved as you intend.

Comment: Yep, I have the following text in my File Name Patterns box: *.xml but it still gives me '0 results in empty scope' in the search results (even though I know, of course, that the string I am searching for is there)

Comment: In my installation of ADT 22.3.0 this works as intended. I guess it could be a bug introduced in the later version(s), but it could also be some subtle difference in the sequence of things you're doing.

Comment: Possibly. I did unbind the 'Open search dialog' from Keys preferences and bind 'File Search' to Ctrl+H so perhaps that was the culprit. I figured if this was a universal problem it would come up more in a google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Source tab of the layout file editor, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the Find/Replace dialog. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to traverse through matches of the last search, even when the Find/Replace dialog is closed.

Comment: This works although it doesn't put the results in the search tab and you have to go to each occurrence of a found result one by one. I'll mark this is the accepted answer if no one else comes up with anything better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl + Shift + R for searching the XML file quickly in eclipse.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I'm trying to search the file's contents, not actually look for the file name

Comment: yes, you have specified individual XML file for searching.